# How to implement views to the pagecontrol

Tags: iphone, uiview, uipagecontrol

I'm about to create an App.

It should have 3 main pages. So I thought of achieving this with a PageControl.

I created 3 Views and now i am stuck on the implementation of this PageControl.

Has anyone a good tutorial or a example code where i take can look at (it can be german too)?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816144/uipagecontrol-help

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this Question before :-/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a simple idea of how to use it.

PageController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PageController : UIViewController {
    NSArray * views;
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl * pageControl;

- (IBAction) changePage:(id)sender;
- (void) animateToView:(UIView *)newView;

@end
```

PageController.m:

```
#import "PageController.h"

@implementation PageController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = [views count];
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;

    // Either wire this up in Interface Builder or do it here.
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (IBAction) changePage:(id)sender {
    UIView * newView = [views objectAtIndex:[pageControl currentPage]];
    [self animateToView:newView];
}

- (void) animateToView:(UIView *)newView {
     // You'd have to implement this yourself
}

@end
```

Comment: In PageController.h Correction: @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

Comment: Im having problems switching views, here is my code:    `#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize pageControl;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    //Create UIViews
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]];
    [view1 addSubview:imageView];
    //ditto for image 2
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    views = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:view1, view2, nil];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = [views count];
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
}
@end`

Comment: Ok ive got it set up with 3 programmatically created UIImageViews each with a UIImage.  I understand the concept of calling changePage and it works, but I understand I need to place the first uiimageview on the main view and then everytime the changePage method is called I have to "add 320 px to its position, remove it from view, add 320 pixels to the new view"?

Comment: Yes, but rather than hard-coding 320, it's better to calculate the position based on the superview's bounds.