# how to proper use pagecontrol in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

I have 3 pages data so I want to use page control,,,
all the data is in one class, so what to do, tell me proper way, because this is first time I am going to use page control,,,

I have nothing except labels and text field of big form, so I have to show them in 2 or 3 pages in page control,,,,

if someone is not clear about question, so he/she may ask again to me .....

Comment: there are plenty of documents regarding this. Stackoverflow itself contains many questions on it. You should have checked them before asking a very general question of this nature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the developer documentation of [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And check out this sample code from Apple - [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I agree but can't you tell me some sort of easy coding, I don't like Class Refrences, they helps less and confuses more :-P

Comment: It is giving code sign error in compiling, so now I am ready code for understanding,,,,

Comment: @Viraj, can U give me easy way, I have 12 label and 12 textfields, so just I want per page 4 of them, so it be 3 pages,

Comment: Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Comment: apple class reference has the worst way, so please tell me easy coding, happy coding,

Comment: Change the project settings and run it on a simulator.

Comment: I did it, but why don't you tell me easy way, just simple coding for manuplating labels and textfields on pagecontrol,

Comment: Check these questions - It will give you what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816144/uipagecontrol-help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230665/how-to-implement-views-to-the-pagecontrol

Comment: Read this also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103915/is-uipagecontrol-useless-by-itself/4014230#4014230

Comment: @Viraj: Apple's example code for PageControl is very confusing for me as well - it gives no clue how to wire up everything and speaking of explaining, their code with comments is simply not enough for novice programmers to grasp the concept :(

Comment: @delirus: Yes, I agree. But for Veer's problem, I felt the sample code PageControl would be the most apt for starting up with. It provides us with a set of different views to start up from and we can add our own elements in the different views.

Comment: @Viraj: of course Apple's examples should be the first place to start with if one does not have any other reliable resource like books/gurus. My comment was rather complaining than adding anything to the discussion. Sorry. Anyway it seems strange to me that I didn't find a single book that has a chapter on UIPageControl. The control seems to be undervalued a bit.

Comment: @delirus: I completely agree with you. The control is definitely undervalued. But, UIPageControl in itself is useless. It is always to be used in conjunction with UIScrollView.