# Swipe view and view controller

Tags: objective-c, view, controller

I'm trying to make a swipe navigation but i block on one point..
I must to create several views with one viewcontroller that controls them for swiping ? 
Or I must to create one view with one viewcontroller each time ?

Thx you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends.
**1,** You can either have multiple viewControllers embedded in a single UINavigationController and use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer and a Segue on every viewController to travel between them hierarchically....

**2,** ... or you could use one single viewController with multiple UIViews and a UIPageControl (like in the default Weather app). You can find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230665/how-to-implement-views-to-the-pagecontrol) and [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html).

The second option will give you smoother scrolling experience, but for showing entire different viewControllers i think you have to use the firsts option.

There is also the matter of transferring data between the views/viewControllers. In the first option you should use Segues and delegate protocols to transfer data between viewControllers.