# How do you combine UIScrollview with UIPagecontrol to show different views?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I've searched and searched for a tutorial for this but none of them are what I'm looking for. I've tried Apple's sample but it is just colors and I don't know how to make it views. All I'm looking for is a screen that will page while showing the page control. Each time the scroll view pages i want it to show a completely different view. Not different text or images but a different view. A lot like the home screen of the iPhone or ESPN Scorecenter app. Please Help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

I created this universal solution as examples found was to complicated and this is readable for me, code should be self explanatory.

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    _pageControlUsed = YES;
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.contentSize.width /_pageControl.numberOfPages;
    CGFloat x = _pageControl.currentPage * pageWidth;
    [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(x, 0, pageWidth, _scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    _pageControlUsed = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (!_pageControlUsed)
            _pageControl.currentPage = lround(_scrollView.contentOffset.x /
            (_scrollView.contentSize.width / _pageControl.numberOfPages));
}
```

Comment: actually, look down at @datinc's answer. very clean and simple.

Comment: @Rene Dohan how to get same effect on click changePage and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. zip zip movement of images on scroll same has click on page control.

Comment: @ReneDohan absolutely! I do love that about SO! I only pointed the other solution out because yours had so many up-votes, and IMHO the newer answer was better.  :-)

Comment: I still use this solution because I like that DidEndDecelerating is called just once on and of event instead of multiple times in scrollViewDidScroll... This can have some other unwanted consequences...

Answer (score 14):

This does the same as @ReneDohan answer without the need for variable to store state

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    CGFloat x = self.pageControl.currentPage * self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, 0) animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.isDragging || scrollView.isDecelerating){
        self.pageControl.currentPage = lround(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / (self.scrollView.contentSize.width / self.pageControl.numberOfPages));
    }
}
```

Comment: Bravo! This worked for me when I connected the scroll view delegate to the view controller.

Answer (score 4):

Try out this framework : https://github.com/AdrianFlorian/AFImageViewer to present images in a scroll view using a page controll to indicate the current page.

I have't added documentation yet, but you can see examples if you clone the project.

You can easily:
    - download images from the internet in a separate thread by only giving an array of urls (image urls)
    - give it an array of UIImage objects
    - implement a delegate and manage the image for each page yourself

Answer (score 1):

There is a related question: [How do I use UIPageControl to create multiple views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816144/uipagecontrol-help), a really good way to do that is explained in this blog post: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a demo project for this question. Please visit:
https://github.com/lenhhoxung86/PageControlDemo