# Programmatically Linking UIPageControl to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am making a simple slideshow view within my app.  I'd like to link my UIPageControl to my UIScrollView.  This shouldn't be too difficult, but I haven't been able to find a simple solution anywhere.  Below is my code.

HelpViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HelpViewController : UIViewController{
}
@end
```

HelpViewController.m

```
#import "HelpViewController.h"

@interface HelpViewController ()

@end

@implementation HelpViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 62, 320, 404);
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 404);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
    UILabel *label  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 21)];
    [label setText:@"Hello"];
    [scrollView addSubview:label];
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init]; 
    pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(110,5,100,100); 
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 2; 
    pageControl.currentPage = 0; 
    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: I answered this correctly here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533047/how-do-you-combine-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-to-show-different-views/14230698#14230698 better to have answer on one place… I fixed proposed changes there.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Maybe this works for you

Don't forget to set the UIScrollView's delegate = self (or wherever you have the selector below).

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width; // you need to have a **iVar** with getter for scrollView
    float fractionalPage = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page; // you need to have a **iVar** with getter for pageControl
}
```

For your code it then would be:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HelpViewController : UIViewController{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl * pageControl;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "HelpViewController.h"

@interface HelpViewController ()

@end

@implementation HelpViewController
@synthesize scrollView=scrollView_;
@synthesize pageControl=pageControl_;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 62, 320, 404);
    self.scrollView = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame] autorelease];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 404);
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
    UILabel *label  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 21)];
    [label setText:@"Hello"];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:label];
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.pageControl = [[[UIPageControl alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(110,5,100,100); 
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 2; 
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0; 
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        float fractionalPage = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
        NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page; 
    }


@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!  The logic is sound, but I don't quite understand the implementation.  I have updated my posting to include my full .h and .m files.

Comment: updated! just copy the code.. :) ... it's untested, theres maybe a typo. But it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much.  You've saved me a lot of headache.  My issue ended up being with the delegate.

Comment: Technically, you don't *need* to have the scrollView in an ivar as you state. It is provided to the delegate methods as a parameter.

Answer (score 54):

This is actually quite simple to setup. Firstly you need to create the scroll view and page control. Make sure you implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` in the interface of the class.

```
    UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    UIPageControl * pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, scrollView.frame.size.width, 20)];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = scrollView.contentSize.width/scrollView.frame.size.width;
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then you need to add the following two methods:

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    CGFloat x = pageControl.currentPage * scrollView.frame.size.width;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, 0) animated:YES];
}

-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    NSInteger pageNumber = roundf(scrollView.contentOffset.x / (scrollView.frame.size.width));
    pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber;
}
```

These methods add the required communication between the page control and the scroll view.

Comment: To correctly determine the pageNumber you need to multiple by the pageControl.numberOfPages

Answer (score 4):

Following code will work for Swift:

```
func addScrollView() {        
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    let numberOfPages: CGFloat = 4
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width * numberOfPages, height: scrollView.frame.height * numberOfPages)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    let pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.frame.height - 37, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: 37))
    pageControl.numberOfPages = Int(numberOfPages)
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let value = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(round(value))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to get exact page index without rounding off the value simply put the pagecontrol.currentpage in the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating delegate method of scroll view.This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are great but I'd like to offer an alternative solution, using [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa)!

The following code makes an assumption that you have a property called `scrollView` and one called `pageControl`.

```
[RACObserve(self.scrollView, contentOffset)
  subscribeNext:^(NSValue* value){
      CGPoint offset = [value CGPointValue];
      CGFloat fractional = offset.x/self.scrollView.width;
      [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:lroundf(fractional)];
  }];
```

All that's going on here is you're observing change on the contentOffset property of the scrollView and calculating the page index on every next event (i.e. every time the property value changes).

The only downside of this is that you have to unbox the `CGPoint` but on the upside there's no `UIScrollViewDelegate` code needed at all!