# UIScrollView and UIPageControl

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm new to iOS development and have been having trouble figuring out how to use `UIPageControl`. I want to have one part of the screen be a menu with different options that the user can select. I want to do this using `UIPageControl`. From what I understand I have to use a `UIScrollView` with pagination turned to `YES`. All the information I have found online is either not that good or very out of date.

I want to know how to get the scroll view working with the page controller.

If you know of any good tutorials on this or don't mind explaining it I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: This example can help you: [link](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/09/26/uipagecontrol-uiscrollview/) Also a good reference is Apple Example: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically Linking UIPageControl to UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198732/programmatically-linking-uipagecontrol-to-uiscrollview)

Comment: Here's another example: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_paging