# How to add PageviewController inside collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UICollectionView` inside a `UIViewController`. Now, I need to add a `UIPageViewController` inside the custom `UICollectionViewCell` that i created. How can i do this ?

Here's my approach.

`UIVIewController.h` class

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        PViewCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell.pageViewController addTarget:self action:@selector(changed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return cell;

}
```

`PViewCollectionViewCell.h` Class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface PViewCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pageBannerImageView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageViewController;

- (IBAction)pageVIewChanged:(id)sender;



@end
```

Comment: Which do you want, UIPageViewController or UIPageControl - they are very different things.

Comment: I am looking for `UIPageViewController `

Answer (score 0):

You are asking "How to implement [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html)" and giving code example with [UIPageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/index.html). It is a completely different thing. I would never recommend implementing UIPageViewController on UICollectionViewCell, because it might kill your performance. The best approach would be UIScrollView + UIPageControl.

On your UICollectionViewCell add UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Also, enable paging on your scroll using:

```
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198732/programmatically-linking-uipagecontrol-to-uiscrollview) you can find many answers which are well described. I would say that it does not really matter where you implement pagination - on UIView or UICollectionViewCell. The only thing you should do is make sure that UICollectionView scroll gesture does not cancel your UICollectionView pagination scroll gesture.

Please, do not duplicate questions. First have a look on existing posts and create your own one only if you did not find anything.