# page control current page not changing when i scroll my image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol, pagecontrol

page control current page not changing when I scroll my image but when I click page control its works fine with changing image also scroll fine above is my code
help me to find my mistakes and correct it

```
   scrollViewImage.delegate = self;
 int x=0;
scrollViewImage.pagingEnabled=YES;
NSArray *image=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png",@"4.png", nil];

int totalImage = (int)image.count;
for (int i=0; i<image.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 140)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[image objectAtIndex:i]];
    x=x+[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    [scrollViewImage addSubview:img];
}

scrollViewImage.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x, 115);
scrollViewImage.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 0);


// page control
   pageController = [[UIPageControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 320, 36)];

[pageController addTarget:self action:@selector(pageChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.numberOfPages=totalImage;

pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  }
- (void)viewDidUnload {

[super viewDidUnload];
}
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {

UIPageControl *pager=sender;
int page = pager.currentPage;
CGRect frame = scrollViewImage.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollViewImage scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}




- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGFloat viewWidth = scrollViewImage.frame.size.width;

int pageNumber = floor((scrollViewImage.contentOffset.x - viewWidth/2) / viewWidth) +1;
   pageController.currentPage = pageNumber;
pageController.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor ];
[scrollViewImage setContentOffset: CGPointMake(scrollViewImage.contentOffset.x,0)];
}

- (void)pageChanged {

int pageNumber = pageController.currentPage;
CGRect frame = scrollViewImage.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width*pageNumber;
frame.origin.y=0;
[scrollViewImage scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198732/programmatically-linking-uipagecontrol-to-uiscrollview

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this below method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width; // you need to have a **iVar** with getter for scrollView
    float fractionalPage = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page; // you need to have a **iVar** with getter for pageControl
}
```