# Embedding UIPageControl inside a TabBarController stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm building an application which has a TabBarController at the top level. Contained within one of the tabs there is a tableview, and when a row is selected, I'd like to go to a set of 5 views, controlled via a UIScrollViewDelegate and UIPageControl.

I've built a basic app with the UIScrollViewDelegate and UIPageControl, based Derek Bredensteiner's code in this answer: [How do I use UIPageControl to create multiple views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816144/uipagecontrol-help)

It works fine as a stand alone application, ie: when the ViewController code is called directly from the AppDelegate via:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But when I try to call the same code from my tableview code, I am getting a black screen. I've also tried using **presentModelViewController** and I get the UIPageViewControl dots but the rest is black.

```
LearnPageViewController *phoneContentController = [[LearnPageViewController alloc] init] ;
//  [self presentModalViewController:phoneContentController animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:phoneContentController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work by adding a new window property @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window; but it doesn't sound right. There is a window property up on the AppDelegate and now another one 2 levels down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by adding a new window property @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window; but it doesn't sound right. There is a window property up on the AppDelegate and now another one 2 levels down.